# mysql queryes not work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Have code in alone sript for ajax including,

```
   $connection = mysqli_connect($db_config['server'],$db_config['db_user'],$db_config['db_pass']);
if (!$connection)
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_config['db_name']);

$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
echo "test: <br>";
print_r($test);
```

but it returns nothig, if i call:

```
//db connect
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_config['server'],$db_config['db_user'],$db_config['db_pass']);
if (!$connection)
    die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_config['db_name']);

$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");

print_r($connection);
```

returns:

mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.13-log [server_version] => 50613 [stat] => Uptime: 7999358 Threads: 4 Questions: 656648624 Slow queries: 9090 Opens: 3348364 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 1999 Queries per second avg: 82.087 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 5759563 [warning_count] => 0 )

Comment: mysql or mysqli ? they are two different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you connected by mysqli and you used mysql.

change that

```
  $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
```

to

```
 $test = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM chat");
```

and then you need to fetch your query like that

```
 $row= mysqli_fetch_array($test) ;
 echo $row['some_column'];
```

this is whole code:

```
 $connection =mysqli_connect($db_config['server'],$db_config['db_user'],$db_config['db_pass']);
 if (!$connection)
  die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_config['db_name']);

  $test = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($test) ;
  echo $row['some_column']."<br />"; //you need to put the column you want to output.
```

Comment: He will also need to pass the connection to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: if you want you can pass connection , if you dont pass its not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysqli_connect`, but `mysql_query`. You can't mix `mysqli` and `mysql` - use one or the other. Most people will tell you to use `mysqli`. I'd say to use whichever is best for you. In my case, that's `mysql` because I don't have to pass a connection reference to every single call... among other reasons.

Comment: Correct source of the problem, but telling him to go with `mysql_*` is a terrible idea. `mysql_*` is deprecated and should not be added to newly written code. Go with `mysqli_*`, then you'll also possibly have less to change later if you go with the object oriented approach, or start using prepared statements.

Comment: @Thorbear Fair. Personally I use a DB class that I built, which wraps `mysql_` functions. Very easy to change, since I just have to change that one class and I'm done ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As mysql is depricated try using mysqli, pdo or any other.
Code for mysqli is as follow:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database_name");

$test= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM chat") or die($mysqli->error);

if($test->num_rows){
            while($rows = $test->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $data1= $rows['data1'];
                $data2= $rows['data2'];
            }
}
?>
```

$test->num_rows checks for number of results and while loop is used to get all the data returned.